# Pasting from OWA to Excel prompts login

Tags: microsoft-excel, outlook-web-access

We use our OWA for email a lot in our environment and I have noticed that when a user goes to copy text from the OWA and attempt to paste it into Excel, Excel prompts the user to log back into the OWA instead of pasting the text.  If the user pastes it into Excel in a regular text format or double clicks on the cell, it pastes fine.  It seems like when it copies from the OWA, its actually copying HTML.  Anyone have an idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The advice I have come across for this problem is rather meager:

- Microsoft itself recommends copying from OWA to Notepad,
  then re-copying and pasting the data into Excel (yes, seriously).
- Some users report success when opening Excel in Safe mode,
  by either using the `/safe` command argument or by
  pressing and holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while starting Excel.